# Accessing servlet generated objects (JSONObjects) via AJAX and JQuery

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, servlets, gson

I am new to using AJAX and JQuery with Java Servlets. I want to produce a search page that produces a list of search results (like a google page listing). My database query works and returns a JSONObject or a JSONArray.

My code is not working for the JQUERY. I have tried a lot of different versions. The basic error is that the new page after the search just shows the data in the form of an array print. It does not recognise the HTML.

I have shown my code below with the db query removed. The different versions I tried were with various forms of JSON syntax, with and without GSON, and nothing has worked.

The system is Linux.

Any comments would be appreciated, or even a link to a comprehensive example.

search.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#searchbutton').submit(function)
{
    var inputdata = searchText:$("#searchtext").val();
};
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    datatype: "json",
    url:"search",
    data:inputdata,
    success: function(data){
 $("#searchResults").append("<b>data.linkresult</b>")

        });
        });

});

});
 });
```

search.java

```
 protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
  HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
 PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();    
// reading the user input
String searchword= request.getParameter("search");  
String Tmsg = "";
Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();


data.put("searchresult", searchword);


response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(new Gson().toJson(data));
```

search.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Search for a word</title> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/search.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="search">          
         Search<br>
         <div>Word -
            <input id="searchtext" type="text" name="search" size="40px">
        </div>

        <div>
            <input id="searchbutton" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </div>

    </form>      




 <div id="searchresults">

 </div>
```

Result (just this one line is displayed):

```
{"searchresult":"search example"}
```

Answer (score 0):

To parse the Json message received from the servlet, you can achieve this by doing something like this. Lets assume that you have received the following message from the servlet

{"key1":"val1","key2":"val2","key3":"val3"}

And you want it to be displayed in a table.

```
success: function(data){
var output = '<table>';
for ( var key in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        output += "<tr>";
        output += "<td>" + key + "</td>";
        output += "<td>" + data[key] + "</td>";
        output += "</tr>";
    }
}
output += "</table>";
$("#searchResults").empty();
$("#searchResults").append(output);

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that and it failed again. The problem is connected somehow to the actual transfer of data and the system is failing to understand the rendered page is html. I think this is directly related to ajax somehow and now the coding in the Java.